# set setInterval for 2 functions to run alternately

Tags: jquery

I want to call two set Interval functions alternately after 2 seconds
Like I want that after 2 seconds first function runs then after 2 sec , second functions run then again repeat the process
something like this:-

```
$('.slider ul').animate({marginLeft:'-' + slider_w},500)
},2000),setInterval(function(){
$('.slider ul').animate({marginLeft:'0'},500)
},2000)
```

Comment: Sounds like what you really want is recursion -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/bz2bg11b/**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use counter to call functions alternatively.

```
var counter = 1;
setInterval(function() {
    if (counter++ % 2) {
        func1(); // Call Function 1
    } else {
        func2(); // Call Function 2
    }
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

With your current setup, you do not need to alternate. You can simply check the current css value

```
var newMargin = 0;

setInterval(function() {
    if ($('.slider ul').css('margin-left') == 0) {
        newMargin = slider_w * -1;
    } else {
        newMargin = 0;
    }

    animateSlider(newMargin);
}, 2000);

function animateSlider(newMargin) {
    $('.slider ul').animate({
        marginLeft: newMargin
    }, 500);
}
```